# WIX Toolset MSI. How to change the order of creating shortcuts?

Tags: wix

I create 3 desktop shortcuts as usual. They are created in the order 1, 2 and 3. How can I make them created in a different order? For example 1, 3 and 2. I didn't find any suitable attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can make the creation through Custom Action.
2. If the shortcuts are in the same feature, then they are created in order by name. In this case, you can change their name and the order of creation will change.
3. If they are in several features, then they will also be created by name, if there are no other actions between them. So for example you can create a shortcut then copy files then create another shortcut.